# Show the maximum order statistic ${X}_{(n)}$ is not a sufficient statistic.

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Suppose $X_1,...X_n$ are independet random variables with $X_i \sim U( θ,θ+1)$
where θ is unknown.
Show the maximum order statistic ${X}_{(n)}$ is not a sufficient statistic.

I know the pdf is: $f_\theta (x_i) = 1_{\theta<x_i<\theta+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

If you take a look at the joint distribution of your samples
\begin{align*}
f_\theta(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=\prod_{i=1}^n f_\theta(x_i)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n 1_{\theta<x_i<\theta+1}\\
&= 1_{\theta<x_{(1)}}1_{x_{{(n)}<\theta+1}}
\end{align*}
You can check that there is no way of writing this as
 a function of $x_{(n)}$ only.